# How to automatically enter the password when signing in iTextSharp

Tags: .net, itext, digital-signature, smartcard, x509certificate2

I must use a certificate stored in a Security token. I can access it from the windows certificate store, but the device has a password, so is displayed a pop-up with a input field and I used **CspParameters** as automatically enter the password.

However when I sign thousands of files that pop-up enter the password again appears.
This is the code who I use for load the certificate:

```
public X509Certificate2 loadX509byPass()
        {
            var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
            var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, SerialNumber, false);
            var cert = certificates[0];
            store.Close();

            var pass = new SecureString();           
            char[] array = Password.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char ch in array)
            {
                pass.AppendChar(ch);
            }
             var privateKey = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
             CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
             privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
             privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
               new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(),
             pass);  

            var rsaCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);              
            // set modified RSA crypto provider back
            cert.PrivateKey = rsaCsp;
            return cert;
        }
```

and when sign file:

```
                         Cert = SingletonCA.Instance.loadX509byPass();
                         ....
                         BcX509.X509Certificate bcCert = DotNetUtils.FromX509Certificate(Cert);
                        var chain = new List<BcX509.X509Certificate> { bcCert };
                        var FontColour = new BaseColor(0, 0, 255); 
                        IExternalSignature pks = new X509Certificate2Signature(Cert, "SHA1");                        

                        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Is possible send the password in the code for not display this message?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you calling `loadX509byPass()` just once or for each signature again and again?

Comment: Yes bro. I think USB token was denied me

Comment: Yes, just once for once file.

Comment: Once for each file? Why not simply once?

Comment: I don't understand the use case. What is the signature supposed to indicate, if not some sort of approval (which of course requires a manual entry)? The idea of caching the PIN is violating any idea of security.  If its more a kind of integrity protection, then a  digital signature is not a very convincing choice. If you insist on it, there are cards not requiring a PIN for the use of the key.